# Visual Studio: cannot open source file even though it shows in Solutions Explorer

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

Running into a problem where Visual Studio's build fails when it fails to locate CAPE/CAPE.c, even though the file is clearly included in the project configurations. [picture of Visual Studio configurations and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80L85.png)

Comment: Does the file exist?  Is visual studio looking at the directory you think it is looking at - open the vcxproj file in notepad and look for CAPE.c - is the path correct?

Comment: The include folders you're showing in that picture have nothing to do with actual source file participation in the vcprojx of your project. Unless this project, for whatever insane and nefarious reason, is `#include`-ing .c files in other .c files, changing the include paths won't help. The project configuration was told where the files were located when conceived. Since then someone (maybe you) *moved* the source files somewhere else, and now the build system cannot find them. Either move them back or update the project file to point to the changed location. That's it.

Comment: I downloaded the project from Github and didn't move around any of the source files. I'm confused why the Visual Studio is able to find the source files from the ./bson folder but it is not able to locate the ones inside ./CAPE, even though they are found in the same folder.